# Are these two probability equal or not?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Suppose there is a distribution $D$.

$x$ is extracted directly from $D$.

$s = (a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)$ is $n$ samples i.i.d from $D$.

then extract a sample $y$ from $s$.

Can $y$ be interpreted as being extracted directly from $D$?

I mean, $x$ and $y$ have same meaning?

Comment: It sounds like you are asking something like "Is the probability that you get an ace of spades you select a single card from a standard deck of cards the same as the probability that you get an ace of spades if you select a single card from a hand of several cards which itself was randomly selected from a standard deck of cards."  If that is what you are asking, the answer is yes.  It is difficult to tell if this *is* what you are trying to get at due to several grammatical errors and lack of clarity when trying to get concepts across.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.   It matters not how many sample you generate.

Since each set of samples in $(a_k)_{1\leq k\leq n}$ is selected independently and identically from $D$ (ie with replacement after each sampling), therefore it does not matter which sample you select $y$ from, it has the same probability of having a particular identity as if you had selected it dirrectly from from $D$.

Take a standard deck of 52 cards.  Draw a hand of five cards, record it as $a_1$, replace it, shuffle and draw another, recording it as $a_2$, and so forth.  Among $n$ such drawings you pick an index from 1 to $n$ without bias, then select one of the cards in that indexed hand.   The probability that that card is the ace of clubs is: $1/52$, exactly as if you had drawn a single card straight from the deck.